# regular expression to match a ascii character

Tags: regex, scala

I want to match a regular expression for the string

```
2=abc\u000148=123\u0001
```

Explanation

1. Key value pairs separated by `SOH(\u0001)` characeter

   - Key - Number
   - Value can be string of number ,alphabets,decimals
2. key and value are separated by `"="`

The regex I tried is

```
[0-9]=.*[u0001]+
```

but it does not  matches properly

**Update**

- I have a list of numbers `val num =Seq(2,3,4)`
- Instead of finding I want to remove the matches from the string
- keys for which I want to replace is from values inside  list **num**

Input

```
 2=abc\u000148=123\u00013=def\u0001
```

Output It is the filtered string

```
148=123\u0001 ,where keys which match value 2 and 3 are removed from list

object Main extends App {

  val s = "2=abc\u000148=123\u00013=def\u0001"
  val num = Seq(2,3)
  for (e <- num) {
    val p = s"(\\$e+)=([^\u0001]*)".r
    test(p)

  }

  private def test(p: Regex) = {
    p.findAllIn(s).matchData foreach {
      m => println(m.group(1) + " : " + m.group(2))

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it JavaScript?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated tags but regex works same everywhere i guess

Comment: Then you may try `"""(\d+)=([^\u0001]*)"""`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/MzDbWw/1 it doesnt work

Comment: Excuse me, in PCRE regex, you can't use `\uXXX`, it supports `\x{XXXX}`. Next, does your string contain a literal `\u0001` (6 char string), and not a char SOH char? I ask because in the regex fiddle, you put `8=abc\u0001` where there is no SOH char.

Comment: \u0001 is ascii value for SOH

Comment: Yeah, then why do you test against `\u0001` and not `SOH`? You should only test against *real-life* inputs. Use my pattern in the Scala code. See https://ideone.com/f6qMte

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155310/discussion-between-coder25-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: To answer the filtering part, please show your code to see how you store the matches.

Comment: ok let me update

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the pattern dynamically like this:

```
s"\\b(?:${num.mkString("|")})=[^\\u0001]*\\u0001*"
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:num1|num2...|numN)` - any of the values in the `num` variable
- `=` - an equal sign
- `[^\u0001]*` - zero or more chars other than a SOH char (a char with the decimal code of 1)
- `\u0001*` - zero or more SOH chars.

See a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/CbGlCK):

```
val num = Seq(2,3)
val s = "1041=pqr\u000148=xyz\u000122=8\u00012=abc\u000148=123\u00013=def\u0001"
val pattern = s"\\b(?:${num.mkString("|")})=[^\\u0001]*\\u0001*"
// println(pattern) // => \b(?:2|3)=[^\u0001]*\u0001*
println(s.replaceAll(pattern, ""))
// => 1041=pqr\u000148=xyz\u000122=8\u000148=123\u0001
```

Comment: thks it works .I have some further use case shall I update the question or post a new one

Comment: Please update the question, or let me know via a comment. If you choose the comment, and that concerns sharing the code, please use IDEONE fiddles.

Comment: @coder25: You need to filter the results as a post-process step. You may use a regex for that, too, but it will look cumbersome. It would be best if you showed your code, so as not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @coder25 Ok, I am just trying to accommodate to your code. See the updated answer.

Comment: my expected output is `148=123\u0001` i.e the  actual string s has stripped off the matched groups

Comment: But isn't `\u0001` (SOH) char a *delimiter* that should be removed after "splitting"? Do you want [this](https://ideone.com/NuppHx)? Or like [this](https://ideone.com/3cpvQO)?

Comment: so the String can we very long like 1041=pqr\u000148=xyz\u000122=8\u00012=abc\u000148=123\u00013=def\u0001,final output should be the filtered string which is 1041=pqr\u000148=xyz\u000122=8\u000148=123\u0001

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155320/discussion-between-coder25-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: thks but can u futher explai\n what mkString("|")"is doing and [^\\u0001]* needed

Comment: @coder25 The `[^\u0001]*` is described. `.mkString` joins the items of `num` into a string with `|` as a delimiter (`num(3,5)` => `3|5`). See the demo pattern: `\b(?:2|3)=[^\u0001]*\u0001*`.  Here, `(?:2|3)` matches `2` or `3`, `[^\u0001]*` matches 0+ chars other than SOH char.

Comment: instead [^\u0001]* cant it be any string .For my understanding can we use regex for this,I mean s"(\\$e+)=([^\u0001]*)".r.

Comment: @coder25 Sorry, that sounds like something that is no longer related to the question. However, let me clarify: to match any chars but some specified chars, you want to use a *negated character class*, like `[^sql]*` to match zero or more chars other than `s`, `q`, `l` (and it will match `abc` in `abcsql` string). To match any chars excluding a sequence, you might want to just `(?:(?!sql).)*`, but there are also other means to make it more readable.

Comment: thks but what is the difference if we use .r

Comment: @coder25 @coder25: The `.r`  compiles a regex object. Without it, it is just a string pattern. See a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/x1SL4W) with `replaceAllIn` and a `"...".r` pattern. Note that when you use it with `replaceAllIn`, you have access to the capturing group values, and can use closures. In your scenario, you just do not need it.